# Find the following integral:

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration, partial-fractions

Find $$\int \sqrt{\tan x}dx$$

My attempt:

$$\text{Let}\ I=\int \sqrt{\tan(x)}dx$$

$$\text{Let}\ u=\tan(x), du=(1+\tan^{2}(x))dx$$

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{u^{2}+1}$$

$$\text{Let}\ v=\sqrt{u}, dv=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$$

$$I=2\int \frac{v^{2}}{v^{4}+1}$$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx$$

$$\text{Let}\ t=\frac{1}{v} \therefore dt=\frac{-dv}{v^2}$$

$$\therefore I=\int \frac{\frac{1}{t^2}}{1+\frac{1}{t^4}}\times\frac{-dt}{t^2}$$

$$I=-\int \frac{dt}{1+t^4}$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can know whether there is a duplicate before I post? I will go through the thread and see if the answer I am looking for is there. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the question. I do not think it is a duplicate now.

Comment: You are asking how to compute the integral in the last line. See accepted answer to that question. It is defenitely a duplicate

Comment: It is always difficult to determine whether your question have been asked before, just guess how would could look like the most confirmistic variant of your question and use search bar

Answer (score 2):

First let us compute the following $$\int(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}) dx=\int\frac{\sin x +\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x\cdot \cos x}}dx=\sqrt 2\int\frac{d(\sin x - \cos x)}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x -\cos x)^2}}$$ which is same as the  $$\sqrt 2\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\sqrt 2\sin ^{-1}z+c$$ Again compute $$\int(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x})dx=\int\frac{\sin x -\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x\cdot \cos x}}dx=\sqrt 2\int\frac{-d(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sqrt{(\sin x+\cos x)^2 -1} } dx$$ and this is same as $$-\sqrt 2\int \frac {dw}{\sqrt{w^2 -1}}=-\sqrt 2\int\frac{\sec u\tan u}{\tan u} du=-\sqrt 2\ln(\sec u +\tan u)+C$$ where $w=\sec u$. Now add both the integrals to obtain the result.

Comment: I think you need to carry this one out.  I don't think the minus integral works out as well.